# How do I include configuration files with Maven Appassembler?

Tags: configuration, maven, packaging, appassembler

I'm using the [Maven Appassembler](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html) plugin to package my application. I'd like to package some configuration files with the application. I've found the [`configurationDirectory`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html#configurationDirectory) and [`includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html#includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath) parameters, but I haven't found how I should create (and populate) that configuration directory. I've tried putting the files in `src/main/resources`, but that just puts them in the jar file for my project.

What is the "proper" way to do this, using maven?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the appassembler plugin in the current release version.  Typically, the plugin is used in conjunction with the assembly plugin to produce the final artifact, in which you can include the reference to your configuration directory. However, if you'd like to have a functional structure from just the appassembler plugin you need to manually copy the files into place. An example using the antrun plugin with a `src/main/conf` directory can be found here: [http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/archiva/trunk/archiva-jetty/](https://github.com/apache/archiva/tree/archiva-1.3/archiva-jetty)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the plugin uses the directory `src/main/config`.

Is possible to change the source for the config files using the parameter `<configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/config</configurationSourceDirectory>`

Comment: This is the real answer together with adding `<copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>`.

Answer (score 1):

When I include the  copyConfigurationDirectory property, it copies the config files and bundles them properly.

```
  <configurationDirectory>etc</configurationDirectory>
  <configurationSourceDirectory>src/main/config</configurationSourceDirectory>
  <copyConfigurationDirectory>true</copyConfigurationDirectory>
```

I have a different problem though.  I would like to filter my config files before copying, which is giving me some trouble.

Comment: I have the same requirement but failed to find a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that is does not generate the bin scripts for different platforms. The [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) can create (package(s) {tar.gz, zip}) for distribution. These are configured through a assemble.xml. You specify which files go in (with what options (chmod)), etc. It can also filter files (search/replace values within them). etc.

Answer (score 0):

Years later and in version 1.10 of the plugin there is now a preAssembleDirectory configuration option.  Unfortunately I don't find it flexible enough for my needs because it copies directly into assembleDirectory and does not allow to specify a target directory path within assembleDirectory.